# CS0443 Syntax error; value expected on a Length function

Tags: c#

I am just starting C# and I thought I could write something of my own. I tried to write a program that writes all the arguments and unlike C++, there are no argc and argv. This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArgWrite
{
    class ArgWrite    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int i;
            i = 0;
            int amt = ArgLenth(args);
            for (i = 0; i <= amt; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static int ArgLenth(string[] args)
        {
            return args[].Length();
        }

        private static void Write(string[] args, int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Just for a note: The extra functions are made by VS2017 to simplify my code.

Comment: `args[].Length()` should be `args.Length`. Why did you create a method to return this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this like remove `int i; i= 0;`. More on for loops, while loops and do while loops is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArgWrite
{
    class ArgWrite    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                string arg = args[i];
                Console.WriteLine("arg index: [{i}] argument is {arg} ");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to throw Out-of-range exception if you decided to answer "typographical error" question?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following error:

```
return args[].Length();
```

it should be

```
return args.Length();
```

However, I think you could write your sample more simple, without the for statement and just using the foreach statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

```
    using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{arg} ");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```